# Middle school book where girl discusses Arabian Nights on a sleepover/camping trip

Tags: identification-request

I unfortunately don't have much info on these books other than my sister and I read them in our middle school library. I can remember that the main character (a young girl) either had a sleepover/camping trip with a friend and discusses Arabian Nights. They also compare pomegranates to a chest and the main girl is confused and asks her dad what a pomegranate looks like, which he then buys for her when they go shopping.
There is also a part possibly in another book, unsure if it is a series, where she gets a perm for her hair and hates it.

As far as we know it wasn't a translation and was just in English. Neither of us can remember the cover or what the actual book looked like but I know it was just a paperback. We don't know how old the book is but we read it around 2006-2007 possibly.

Answer (score 4):

*Alice the brave* by Phyllis Reynolds Naylor

Sleep-over scene with her friends Pamela and Elizabeth is at the end of the first chapter and continues on the second:

> Elizabeth opened her bag and pulled out something wrapped in a pillow
> case. I took a look. *Tales from the Arabian Nights*, it read on the
> cover. *Unexpurgated edition*.

> "... So the damsel took a sash of Yemen stuff and doubled it about her
> waist, then tucked up her trousers and showed legs of alabaster and
> above them a hummock of crystal, soft and swelling, and a belly that
> exhaled musk from its dimples, as it were a bed of blood-red anemones,
> and breasts like double pomegranates..."
>
> I tried to imagine double pomegranates, whatever they were, and
> wondered if my breasts would equal even one. Elizabeth's fingers
> fairly flew to the next paper clip.

And at the end of the chapter pomegranates are on the shopping list:

> Dad jotted down something with his pencil, then scanned the list again.
> “What's this? Double pomegranates?”
> I swallowed.
> “This your writing, Al?”
> “Yeah. Pomegranates,” I said.
> He looked at me strangely.
> “Do you suppose a couple will do?”
> “Yeah, two would be perfect,” I told him. “I just want to see what they look like.”

It looks like Alice gets a perm she and her family don't like in *Alice in Rapture, Sort Of*.